# JavaFX GridPane buttons in cells are too far from each other

Tags: javafx, constraints, fxml, gridpane

I wrote a code which adds buttons in a GridPane, everything works as it should when I run the code. Only problem is that the buttons in their cells are too far from each other, the "best" outcome I got is the one below, but it's not good since there's still a barrier between the buttons (and they aren't in the center of the grid).
The code for creating the buttons and adding them to the grid:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                b = new Button(" ");
                b.setMinSize(30, 30);
                b.setMaxSize(30, 30);
                b.setStyle("-fx-font-size:11");
                bCont.TheBoard.add(b, i, j);

//              bCont.TheBoard.setVgap(5.0);
//              bCont.TheBoard.setHgap(5.0);

//              GridPane.setMargin(b, new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
                GridPane.setHalignment(b, HPos.CENTER);
                GridPane.setValignment(b, VPos.CENTER);
                GridPane.setVgrow(b, Priority.ALWAYS);
                GridPane.setHgrow(b, Priority.ALWAYS);
            }
        }
        
        ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        constraints.setPercentWidth(85 / columns);
        RowConstraints rowconst = new RowConstraints();
        rowconst.setPercentHeight(85 / rows);
        for (int t = 0; t < columns; t++) {
            bCont.TheBoard.getColumnConstraints().add(constraints);
        }
        for (int t = 0; t < rows; t++) 
            bCont.TheBoard.getRowConstraints().add(rowconst);
```

Example of the output (first image is board size of 3x3, second is 10x10):

[image]

[image]

And in-case the FXML code of the board is also needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="853.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MS.BoardCONTROLLER">
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="TheBoard" alignment="TOP_CENTER" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="118.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="90.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
      <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" fillHeight="false" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="560.0" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="290.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="700.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="560.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="BackMenu" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#BackMenu" text="Back to menu" />
            <Button fx:id="ResetBoard" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ResetBoard" text="Reset" textFill="RED">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="Music" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#Music" text="Music">
               <HBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" />
               </HBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thank you.

More info - if I make the scene's window smaller as shown in the image below, the cells will be closer to each other (and if I make it even smaller they will "step" on each other):

[image]

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: It's a MineSweeper board, I'm trying to get the buttons to be closer to each other

Comment: first step (after having read the javadoc :) in debugging layout problems is to remove all constraints, hard-coded min/max/pref and css - and play with a very small sample (like 3 * 3) to understand how the layout is working. Or in other words, [mcve] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(App.class.getResource("App.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

primaryStage.setTitle("Example");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();

int i=0;
int j=0;
GridPane gridPane = (GridPane)scene.lookup("#mygrid");
for(i=0;i<30;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<12;j++) {
        Button button1 = new Button(" ");
        gridPane.add(button1, i, j, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

FXML

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="com.zigma.Controller">
    <children>
        <GridPane AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" fx:id="mygrid">
        </GridPane>
        <BorderPane maxHeight="50.0" minHeight="50.0"
            AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0"
            AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
            <center>
                <Button fx:id="mybutton" maxHeight="50"
                    mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0"
                    prefWidth="200.0" text="Button" visible="false" />
            </center>
        </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

You will get this output
[image]

Comment: I added this line "gridPane.add(button1, i, j, 1, 1);" and also changed the FXML file to have the same properties as yours, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: remove the constraints and CSS

Comment: Thank you! Removing all of the constraints I had and changing the FXML file to be similar to yours did the trick.